# jq: file format as filter(-f) vs. library(-L)

Tags: jq

```sh
❯ jq --version
jq-1.6
```

I'm using .jq file as a filter like following, it works:

```sh
❯ cat jq/script.jq
def fi(v):
  v | tostring |
  if test("\\.") then
    "float"
  else
   "integer"
  end;

def estype(v):
  if type=="number" then
    fi(v)
  else
    type
  end;

def esprop(v):
  if type=="object" then
    {"properties":  v | with_entries(.value |= esprop(.))}
  else
    {"type": estype(v)}
  end;

with_entries(.value |= esprop(.))

❯ cat test.json | jq -f jq/script.jq
...(omit results)
```

But when I use it as library, it throw an error:

```sh
# comment the last filter, except the definitions of functions
❯ cat jq/script.jq
def fi(v):
  v | tostring |
  if test("\\.") then
    "float"
  else
   "integer"
  end;

def estype(v):
  if type=="number" then
    fi(v)
  else
    type
  end;

def esprop(v):
  if type=="object" then
    {"properties":  v | with_entries(.value |= esprop(.))}
  else
    {"type": estype(v)}
  end;

# with_entries(.value |= esprop(.))

❯ cat test.json | jq -L jq/script.jq 'import script;'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
import script;
jq: 1 compile error
```

1. What it means and how could I debug and fix this?
2. Are .jq files as a filter or a library has different syntax([doesn't seems like that](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq))?

Comment: `-L` takes as argument `directories`, not files.

Comment: @Philippe In the manual under section [Modules](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Modules) it reads: "For example, with `-L$HOME/.jq` a module `foo` can be found in `$HOME/.jq/foo.jq` and `$HOME/.jq/foo/foo.jq`. If `$HOME/.jq` is a file, it is sourced into the main program."

Comment: @pmf I meant that `-L jq/script.jq` does not work, whereas `-L jq` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1a. What does it mean?

> syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START

This means the parser found an identifier where it was expecting a string. (FORMAT is the token for a formatter like `@csv` or `@text`, while QQSTRING_START is the token for a string, like `"script"`. In practice it's useless to use a formatter here since it won't let you use a non-constant string, but the parser doesn't know that.)

### 1b. How to debug and fix this?

Probably easiest to refer back to the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Modules). It says that the form expect for "import" is

```
import RelativePathString as NAME;
```

and the form expected for "include" is

```
include RelativePathString;
```

It lacks examples to make this 100% clear, but "RelativePathString" is a placeholder - it needs to be a literal string. Try one of these:

```
cat test.json | jq -L jq 'include "script"; with_entries(.value |= esprop(.))'
```

```
cat test.json | jq -L jq 'import "script" as script; with_entries(.value |= script::esprop(.))'
```

Note that the library path should be the directory containing your script, and the difference between include and import.

### 2. Do .jq files used as a filter or a library have a different syntax?

They use the same syntax. The problem was with the import statement, not with the script file.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to provide the module file directly with the option as in the OP `-L jq/script.jq`? Because with an example using `-L$HOME/.jq` the manual under section [Modules](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Modules) states: "If `$HOME/.jq` is a file, it is sourced into the main program."

Comment: @pmf I can't see a way to do that. I think that statement in the manual stands alone as a statement of fact related to the modules system, rather than an illustration. As far as I can tell it [explicitly](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/80052e5275ae8c45b20411eecdd49c945a64a412/src/linker.c#L410-L418) reads `$HOME/.jq` and nothing else in that way.